# Can't access iframe elements with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am attempting to access a button element on the **consent-page** for mail.com.

The URL for the page can be seen here https://www.mail.com/consentpage.

If you have already been to the site, the consent-page can be viewed in a incognito tab.

Sorry I'm not sure if I should post the link or the full html here.

I am trying to access the button with the following tag

```
<button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler" tabindex="0">Agree and continue</button>
```

link: https://ibb.co/R9bFdws

There appear to be multiple iframe posts above the button I tried to access

link: https://ibb.co/cyptbNr

My code thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http:mail.com")
sleep(3)
try: 
  iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[o]
  driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
  button = iframe.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
  #driver.switch_to_default_content()
  driver.quit()

except:
  print('error')
  driver.quit()
```

Getting access to the iframe appears to work, but after that I can not get to the button element.

I have followed the advice of other posting with this question but unfortunately cant seem to get this to work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[o]` o or 0?

Answer (score 0):

You've goat a tricky one.

You've got `iframe`s within `iframe`s loaded by javascript. You need a couple of calls and you need to wait for elements to be available. You also pasted in code errors that needed to be solved.

Addressing all your issues - This works for me...

Add some more imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Then run this:

```py
#updated your URL as your pasted URL wasn't valid
driver.get("https://www.mail.com/consentpage")

#Get iframe 1 - this updates DRIVER to be within that iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".permission-core-iframe")))

#get iframe 2 - this can only be found when driver is inside the first iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

#Wait for the button to fully load 
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))

#click it
button.click()
```

Going forwards - a tip for you is to debug the code. If it's not working as you expect you need to capture and expose the full error, or more simply remove the `try`. Your `try` output just says "error" - that hides anything that actually went wrong. The actual error message it produces tells you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The element with the text as **Agree and continue** is within multiple `<iframe>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.mail.com/consentpage')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.permission-core-iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://plus.mail.com/lt']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.mail.com/consentpage')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='iframe.permission-core-iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://plus.mail.com/lt')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: mail_dot_com]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)